# How do I find a Stronghold in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to know any hints, tips, or pretty much anything on how to find strongholds. I already know that they're frequently found under swamps, and that you can find them with an Eye of Ender, but there has to be an easier way than that right?

Comment: Your information "They can be found under swamps" is wrong, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

There are no easier ways of finding them than using the Eye of Ender, that don't involve cheating.

Load up your world in some chunk explorer and look for blocks "End Portal Frame". That's the easiest, but obviously a cheat.

Now, how to locate the stronghold using about 4 eyes of ender:

The trick with eyes of ender is not to follow them directly. Place a block where you stand. Throw the Eye up in the air. Follow it and place another block where it lands. Return to the first block and look towards the second, then notice characteristic distant features of land, on the horizon, where the line extends. Mark that place with some blocks.

Now wander a good way sideways from the line created that way and repeat the procedure. The stronghold will be where the two lines intersect. Use a map to draft the place and travel there - you'll have it narrowed down to about one biome size.

When you arrive at the approximate location, repeat the whole procedure and you should have the location narrowed down to some 40-50 chunks. This is perfectly sufficient - strongholds are big. Establish a base of operations at the destination, if you still have an Eye, throw it once again to establish direction of search, then just start digging. Strongholds are rather deep, at least halfway between bedrock and surface.

Also, don't start the search from the initial Spawn point - all strongholds are about equidistant from it, so your "sideways travel" may get confused and the two initial lines will point at different strongholds, with nothing at their intersection. Don't start exceptionally far from the spawn either - about 500 blocks is just the right distance.